# excel 2016 xlm install system wide

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, installation

I am trying to install this Excel 2016 extension system wide, but I am unsure on how to do it so it applies for every users.

https://biology-assets.anu.edu.au/GenAlEx/Download.html

One way to install is silently for the user is to put it in the AppData folder of Excel and in the XLSTART folder, which then it automatically loads, but I am unsure how to do it system wide, so every user gets the access to the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put it in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLSTART

or wherever the XLSTART folder is in the Programs file section.